# Get Twitter Users By Location - Tweetsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, tweetsharp

I am new in tweetsharp. I want to learn all twitter users which are close to my location. How can I do that? I am using ASP.NET (C#)  Thanks.

Comment: could you display some effort already taken to solve that?

Comment: I couldn't write deeply codes. I write only  var AramaAyari = new SearchForUserOptions { Q = aranan, Count = 25 };
            var Ara = servis.SearchForUser(AramaAyari);
            foreach (var i in Ara)
            {
                var Kullanıcılar = String.Format("{0} kullanıcısının;{1} takipçişi ve {2} tweeti bulunmakta ", i.ScreenName, i.FollowersCount, i.StatusesCount);
                lstTweets.Items.Add(Kullanıcılar);
            }.

It finds by name